# Implicit cast of class derived from template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting, implicit

I've got a problem with implicit casting, templates and inheritance from template classes. The following is what I extracted from my project, I have left out that some classes are even abstract, but it does not have to do with the case.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

template <typename T> class Base {};
class Derived : public Base<B> {};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base<A>* base = new Derived();
}
```

Basically, I have a template base class `Base` that I derive `Derived : public Base<B>` from. Then I have to cast it to the most general occuring form of Base, which is `Base<A>`.

I would have thought that I can cast an Object deriving from `Base<B>` to `Base<A>` implicitly, as `B` derives from `A`. Am I doing something wrong or how could I cast that *implicitly*? This is important as I need to accept all types of Derived classes in a method of `Base` as a *parameter*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. `Base<A>` has *no* relation to `Base<B>`, regardless of the relation between A and B.

Comment: Well, thanks. How would you attempt to fix that. Would you consider boost::any as an option?

Comment: @opatut: Consider using a template for your method. Without more information, that's all I can suggest.

Comment: The template seems to work, even though I cannot check it using static_assert(std::is_base_of(...)), but that's not too important anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`Base<B>` does not necessarily need to have a relation to `Base<A>`. This doesn't have anything to do with `Derived`. If you want to force such a relation, you're going to need a templated constructor.

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    template <typename TOther>
    Base(const TOther& that)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

Obviously, the implementation would have to depend on the actual implementation of `Base`. Note that this constructor doesn't substitute for the normal copy constructor.

Comment: This won't work as the class "Base" will be part of an engine, and "Other" will be part of the actual application. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not to tell you how to architect your code, but there's no reason that that templated constructor couldn't be in your header file and just call out to a hidden function that does the actual work.

Comment: "Not to tell you how to architect your code" oh you better should - I got confused by all those templates so I actually forgot how they work. Sorry :D I will consider your answer as an option.