# Templated class fails to implicit-cast from std::shared_ptr<T<N>> to std::shared_ptr<const T<N>>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Failing code is as follows:

```
#include <memory>

template<size_t N>
class A
{};

template<size_t N>
int testFct(std::shared_ptr<const A<N>> aptr) { return 1; }

int main() {
    auto APtr = std::make_shared<A<2>>();
    testFct(APtr);
}
```

It is possible to cast implicitly from `std::shared_ptr<T>` to `std::shared_ptr<const T>` in similar situations - why do I get an error informing me that `'std::shared_ptr<A<2ul> >' is not derived from 'std::shared_ptr<const A<N> >'`?

The problem is presumably that there is no relation between [`A<N>` and `A<2>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238551/3098505), but the function is templated to only take one `N`. Can I arrange the function to avoid (re?)templating the class?

On the other hand, adding a function

```
template<size_t N>
int testFct(std::shared_ptr<A<N>> aptr) { 
    return testFct(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<const A<N>>>(aptr)); 
}
```

allows the code to compile (and presumably run without issue).

Comment: FWIW, using `testFct<2>(APtr);` works for me. I am using g++ 4.9.3.

Comment: Function templates require that the argument types match exactly.

Comment: @n.m. Or have a base/derived relationship (hence the error message)

Comment: Using SFINAE may help: [Demo](https://ideone.com/89XNG4).